# Why is sleep in a child process blocking my program?

Tags: c, concurrency, fork, child-process

So I have this simple program that sleeps for 4 second if the value returned by fork is '0' meaning that the child process is executing, I've tried using sleep in child process but the program is blocked, and flushing standard output isn't working...
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  pid_t value = fork();

  if (value == 0) {
    sleep(4);
  }
  
  printf("Value returned by fork: %d\n", value);
  printf("I'm the process N°%d\n", getpid());
  
  return 0;
}
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Output:

```
Value returned by fork: 12618
I'm the process N°12617\
farouk@farouk-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-TP01-1xxx:~/sysexp$  Value returned by fork: 0
I'm the process N°12618
```

[image]

Comment: What output are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Totally tangential to the main problem — Since you are not using either `argc` or `argv`, it would be better to use `int main(void)` in this program.

Comment: You should see the output from the parent and then your command line prompt; then 4 seconds later, you should get output from the child.  If that's not what's happening, maybe your shell has prevented the child from writing to the terminal (see SIGTTOU etc from `<signal.h>`).  What happens if you hit return?  Which platform (o/s, version) are you using?  It works without any signal issues for me on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 with Bash as my shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right I was just using the template main function that my editor provided

Comment: @Shawn I'm expecting the program to terminate when value of fork is 0, but sleep seems to freeze it

Comment: You could delay the parent process's exit using a `wait()` loop: `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) printf("%d: Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);` — and you'd need `#include <sys/wait.h>` too.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I'll update the post with the output I'm getting

Comment: The child's `sleep(4);` puts it to sleep for 4 seconds, but the child process continues afterwards and executes the two `printf()` statements before exiting.

Comment: The parent will exit after printing two lines; the child will wait 4 seconds, then exit after printing two lines

Comment: Your output screenshot looks correct.

Comment: You just need to type a command after the child's output (e.g. `ls`) or even just hit return to get another prompt.  Or put the wait loop into the code so that the parent doesn't exit until the child has exited.

Comment: Please put the output into the question as text, not as an image.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to stop executing, I have to ctrl + c to stop the process

Comment: Why do you think it didn't stop executing? Is it because you didn't see a new shell prompt after four seconds? The shell only prompts once after each command. The parent process printed its lines immediately, then the parent died, and the shell printed its prompt. As far as the shell knows, when the parent terminates, the command is finished. Four seconds later the child printed its lines, but the shell never knew that the child exists.

Comment: It's exited.  You can hit return to see that the shell is waiting for your input.  A control-C interrupt makes the shell respond again.  Your shell prompt is interleaved with the output from the program because you don't make the parent wait.  You could type `ps` to see the commands that are running; the one identified as the child (and the one identified as the parent) will both be missing.  You could type the `ps` before the child's output appears (in the 4 second gap) and you might see the child running.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes that's what I thought

Comment: Nothing is blocked.  We're conditioned to think that if we don't see the shell prompt at the start of the line, it must be because some other program is in the foreground.  But in this case, the shell already printed its prompt and is still waiting for your input, it's just that the background child process spammed more output to the terminal in the meantime.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've tried the process status command and everything is working as expected, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*To allow this question to have an accepted answer.*</sup>

The child process is not blocking the shell.  The shell gave its prompt and the child wrote some output after the prompt, leaving the cursor at the start of a line without a shell prompt visible — because the shell prompt already appeared earlier.

There are a variety of ways around this.

The simplest is just to type a command such as `ps` and hit return, noting that the shell executes it, and that the `ps` output does not list the child process.  If you type the `ps` command quick enough, you might see the child listed in the output before its output appears.

Another is to modify the program so that it waits for all child processes to exit before it exits — using `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  The same code can be used in the child and the parent since the child will have no children of its own.  The call to the wait function will return immediately with a 'no more children' status (error).

<sup>You can find extensive discussion of all this in the comments — I've chosen to make this a Community Wiki answer since there was a lot of activity in the comments that identified the gist of this answer.</sup>